# Unable to repeat code according to user input in python

Tags: python

I started programming a week ago and I decided I should write a program that randomly assigns the numbers for the european lottery. I have a working script that gives the 5 numbers and 2 stars that make a bet. However, I would like the program to print as many bets as the user would like without having to run the program multiple times. I tried to create a class that would be instantiated as many times as the ones the user would require, but it didn't work. This is the script I have as of now:

```
import random

print "This program doesn't increase the chances of winning the lottery!"
numbers[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]

stars=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

a=random.sample(numbers, 5)

a.sort()

b=random.sample(stars, 2)

b.sort()

print "The numbers are", a

print "The stars are", b
```

I understand that to get input from the user I need to use raw_input("Enter number of bets you want here") but then I have no idea how to use that input to repeat the code. Also, if somebody knows how to make the lists shorter, like instead of having to write every number from 1 to 50 just write like 1-50 I would be grateful to know how. Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance.

Comment: `numbers = range(1,51)`

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a loop.

```
import random
numbers = range(1,51)  # [1,2,3,... 49,50]
stars = range(1,12)    # [1,2,3,... 10,11]

def makeNumbers(plays):
    for i in range(plays):  # makes numbers and stars i times
        a = sorted(random.sample(numbers, 5))
        b = sorted(random.sample(stars,2))
        print 'numbers: ', a
        print 'stars: ', b
```

Testing the function

```
>>> makeNumbers(3)
numbers:  [3, 25, 40, 41, 47]
stars:  [8, 11]
numbers:  [22, 25, 42, 47, 50]
stars:  [5, 9]
numbers:  [6, 23, 34, 40, 44]
stars:  [5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a number by:

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter number of bets you want here"))

for i in range(0,number+1):
    # here you will write your code and it will be repeated number times
```

If you want to create a list from 1 to 50, use range:

```
range(1,51)
```

Comment: Not that `range(1, number)` is incorrect - the end is non-inclusive - so entering `1` as number of times will never run, entering `2` will run once etc... (also, maybe make your `//` style comment a proper Python `#` comment)

Comment: `for i in range(1, number)` will loop `number - 1` times, not `number` times. EDIT: looks like Jon beat me to it

Comment: Last note - the `0` in `range(0, number+1)` isn't required (start defaults to 0).